# IE image width cut off

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-9, width

When writing the image, I don't have access to its dimensions, so I cannot specify the exact width and height. The image is 19px * 16px. The only attributes I have are `id`, `class`, `align="absmiddle"` and `border="0"` Chrome, FF and Safari renders it fine as 19x16, but IE cuts it off at 16x16. What am I doing incorrectly here?

**EDIT:**

```
<img align="absmiddle" id="tree_img_0_0_0" border="0" title="tree node" alt="" src="../icons/web/Lminus.png?-=1k23z39">
```

the png like i said is 19px * 16px.

The containing div is

```
<div class="treenode" style="width:100%;font-family:Segoe UI, Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:9.0pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;">
```

Comment: Show the code that has the problem.

Comment: IE9, so its not the IE<6 image problem :(

Comment: I'm thinking it's a styling issue on either the img element (perhaps some width CSS?) or an ancestor element (perhaps overflow: hidden?). It's hard to know without seeing even more of the HTML and CSS, or a link to the page with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in light of IE being frustratingly different, I just ended up making a "draw image" function and calculated a set width instead of using width:100%

Answer (score 0):

It seems not enough evidence, but did you move align attribute to style?

Check out [how to replace absmiddle with css](http://www.web-sheeps.com/rec/69-Image-vertical-align-with-CSS,-avoid-abs).